# Load view from xib in ScreenSaverView, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsview, screensaver

I have a custom `view` in `ScreenView.xib` that I want to load in the `ScreenSaverView`. My `ScreenSaverView` subclass is following :

```
class SwiftScreensaverView: ScreenSaverView {

    override init?(frame: NSRect, isPreview: Bool) {
        super.init(frame: frame, isPreview: isPreview)
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.addSubview(self.loadNib())
    }

    func loadNib() -> NSView {
        var topLevelObjects : NSArray?
        if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: "ScreenView"), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
            let newView =  (topLevelObjects!.first(where: { $0 is NSView }) as? NSView)!
            newView.frame = self.frame
            newView.wantsLayer = true
            newView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
            return newView
        }
        let oldView = NSView.init(frame: self.frame)
        oldView.wantsLayer = true
        oldView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        return oldView
    }
}
```

But, the screen saver in preview displays the view with `green` color, instead of `red` one!

Comment: I don't know, but try the following.  let newView = ScreenView(nibName: "ScreenView", bundle: nil)!

Comment: @ElTomato there is no `ScreenView` class, the `ScreenSaverView` is not happy with external class, so I am trying to load `xib` in the  `ScreenSaverView` subclass itself.

Comment: Try to move out the NSNib instance to see if it's nil first.

Comment: `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: "ScreenView"), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)` is `false`. So `NSNib` is not able to load the `xib`